# Can my firewall block web-based emails?

Tags: email, firewall, hotmail

I am not receiving emails in my hotmail account from one particular address. (They're not being filtered out as junk mail, before you ask)

I have been given the suggestion that they are being blocked by my firewall. Is this possible? I would have thought it couldn't be, since it is web mail and the emails only ever exist on Microsoft's server.

I reckon the problem exists at the sender's end, but they are adamant it doesn't since they can send to everyone else ok. Surely, it can't be a problem at my end, right?

Comment: The sender probably does not have a PTR record properly set up. Hotmail will drop all such e-mail with no notice. If you post the domain of the sender (I don't need the entire e-mail address), I can do an nslookup and check for you for certain.

Comment: Ok. The domain is "@news.groupon.co.uk".

Comment: "I have been given the suggestion that they are being blocked by my firewall." -- for any reasonable definition of "my" and "firewall", that suggestion is nonsensical. There's just no mechanism for anything like that to move a message into your junk folder.

Comment: @ Mike. Good, that's what I told 'em.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the nslookup results. To be honest, I saw groupon, and thought there is no way such a big company would not be set up right, but now I am not so sure:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
>   Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> C:>nslookup server 199.191.128.103
>   Default Server: 
>   rbru.br.rs.els-gms.att.net Address: 
>   199.191.128.103
>
> set q=mx groupon.co.uk Server: 
>   rbru.br.rs.els-gms.att.net Address: 
>   199.191.128.103
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
>   groupon.co.uk   MX preference = 10,
>   mail exchanger =
>   groupon-1.mx.heinlein-support.de
>   groupon.co.uk   MX preference = 20,
>   mail exchanger =
>   groupon-3.mx.heinlein-support.de
>   groupon.co.uk   MX preference = 10,
>   mail exchanger =
>   groupon-2.mx.heinlein-support.de
>
> I pinged
>   groupon-1.mx.heinlein-support.de in
>   another window, and it came back as
>   91.198.250.10
>
> set q=ptr
>   91.198.250.10 Server:  rbru.br.rs.els-gms.att.net Address: 
>   199.191.128.103
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
>   10.250.198.91.in-addr.arpa      name = mx1.heinlein-support.de

The fact is that that unless they are doing something I don't understand the return on that PTR record, mx1.heinlein-support.de, should match the name of the MX 10 record, or the mail will be dropped by Hotmail.

Comment: Interesting. So the bottom line is that Groupon have probably not got their email configured correctly. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: As far as I can see, and I do A LOT of e-mail for a living. I suppose it is possible they have some funky DNS setup I do not have full knowledge of, I installed Exchange 2010 on two continents this week for a company via the Internet actually.